# GpuDelegateV2 Tflite won't accept any parameters

Tags: flutter, tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

I am using tflite_flutter package to load tflite model. I install package by

**flutter pub add tflite_flutter**

**sh install.sh -d** for using GpuDelegateV2

Following example code i copy from documentation.

```
final gpuDelegateV2 = GpuDelegateV2(
    options: GpuDelegateOptionsV2(
    false,
    TfLiteGpuInferenceUsage.fastSingleAnswer,
    TfLiteGpuInferencePriority.minLatency,
    TfLiteGpuInferencePriority.auto,
    TfLiteGpuInferencePriority.auto,
));

var interpreterOptions = InterpreterOptions()..addDelegate(gpuDelegateV2);
final interpreter = await Interpreter.fromAsset('your_model.tflite',
    options: interpreterOptions);
```

But it gives exception **Too many positional arguments: 0 expected, but 5 found.
Try removing the extra positional arguments, or specifying the name for named arguments**
linter also gives red line on "false" parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe documentation is not updated, Because constructor **allows only named parameters** So the code will be like

```
getModel() async {
  final gpuDelegateV2 = GpuDelegateV2(
    options: GpuDelegateOptionsV2(
      isPrecisionLossAllowed: false,
      inferencePriority1: TfLiteGpuInferencePriority.minLatency,
      inferencePriority2: TfLiteGpuInferencePriority.auto,
      inferencePriority3: TfLiteGpuInferencePriority.auto,
    ),
  );

  var interpreterOptions = InterpreterOptions()..addDelegate(gpuDelegateV2);
final interpreter = await Interpreter.fromAsset('your_model.tflite',
options: interpreterOptions);
```

**Now it works fine.**